# How to print username from the given array of object in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to print the username from the given search result array but it does not print anything. Currently, I am trying to append the value from **all_users** array of loop with key and value format such as  **username: value.user.username,**  and now i am printing with another loop, but it's now working.

**Please check the below attachment for array coming**
[image]

Comment: The call to `.get` is asynchronous and returns immediately; when you try to access `search_result` in the line after it, the `.get` has not finished and so `search_result` is still empty. You need to move that code into your `.done` function.

Answer (score 1):

`$(search_result).each(function(index, result) {   // Not working this  console.log(result.username); });` 
The above line must be inside your ajax call's success function definition.